# Why do my mogenerated classes start with double underscores?

Tags: swift, core-data, mogenerator

I'm following this tutorial: http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/ and using the following script to generate the coredata classes for my project:

```
mogenerator -m MyProject/Classes/Model/MyProject.xcdatamodeld -O MyProject/Mogenerator --swift --template-var arc=true
```

However instead of generating a Entity and and _Entity files what I get are _Entity and __Entity. I checked in the obvious places, ensuring my core-data entities are appropriately named and that there are no underscores in the specified class names. Where else could the problem be?

Comment: Are you sure you look for the files in appropriate destinations? Could that be that you had underscores somewhere, then you've fixed that and investigate your project (so that files are generated but not added)? I'd suggest to try the same mogenerator version on a new separate clean project and see if it mangles the filenames, thus you'll certainly know that's something stupid or a bug. (also, I've checked mogenerator's swift templates and didn't see redundant underscores there)